# Discord.py Выполнение команды с таймером

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Пишу бота для дискорда.
Пробовал многое. Не получается выполнить данное действие.
Суть проблемы: Задан таймер(Например каждый час) бот должен выполнить заранее прописанную функцию.
Что у меня получается? - Либо выполняется все по таймеру, но при этом больше бот не реагирует на команды.
Либо бот реагирует на команды в чате, но не выполняет функцию по таймеру.

Comment: Приведите проблемный код

Comment: @dim0n
`@Bot.event
def check():
    user = 'url'
    while True:
        add_info_user(user)
        time.sleep(5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотека discord.py асинхронная. Для подобных задач можно использовать Background Tasks.
Для этого произведите импорт `from discord.ext import tasks`.

Теперь используйте следующий код:

```
yourname.start() # Для запуска вашего таска    

@tasks.loop(hours=1)
async def yourname(): # Назвать функцию можете как угодно.
    # Действия которые вы хотите производить каждый час.

@your_name.before_loop # Это необходимо, чтобы ваш таск ждал, пока бот полностью запустится.
async def yourname2(): # Назвать эту функцию можно тоже как угодно.
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
```

Также хотел бы подметить, что использовать `time.sleep()` в асинхронном коде нельзя. Вместо этого есть `asyncio.sleep()`, соответственно если будете его использовать, не забудьте импортировать.

Подробнее ознакомится с Background Tasks  в оф. документации - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html

Answer (score 1):

```
from threading import Thread
import schedule # pip install schedule
import time

class ScheduledFunction (Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def someFunc(self):
        print("Running scheduled function")
    
    def run (self):
        schedule.every().second.do(self.someFunc)
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    thrd = ScheduledFunction ("Some name")
    thrd.start()
    while True:
        print("Running the main thread")
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

---

> Задан таймер(Например каждый час) бот должен...

Лучше сделать не через `time.sleep()`, а с помощью библиотеки [schedule](https://tirinox.ru/schedule-cron-python/)

---

Так как вы хотите и время считать, и чтобы бот в то же время мог работать - вам нужен дополнительный поток.

В коде выше - создаётся и запускается поток с именем `Some name`, в методе `run()` планируется выполнение другого метода по таймеру - `schedule.every().second.do(self.someFunc)` (можете использовать `schedule.every().hour.do(self.someFunc)`, чтобы выполнять функцию каждый час).

Далее вызывается:

```
schedule.run_pending()
time.sleep(1)
```

это нужно для того, чтобы `scheduler` мог отсчитывать время до следующего вызова метода.

---

А в `main` там временем начинается бесконечный цикл, выводящий просто текст.

Получается что-то вроде:

```
Running the main thread
Running the main thread
Running the main thread
Running the main thread
Running scheduled function
Running the main thread
```

И так до бесконечности...

---

Из вывода программы видно, что ни выполнение `time.sleep(1)` в методе `run()`, ни `while True` в `main` не блокируют друг друга и они прекрасно работают вместе.

---

Теперь вам просто остаётся переписать часть своего кода для использования многопоточности и планировщика задач `:)`